# How best open xml, parse with xslt and show result in browser

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am currently studying ways to present transformed xml files in browsers. My experience with this is minimal, so a number of questions pop up.

I have a transformation test.xslt which transforms input xml to html, and an input file test.xml containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xslt" ?>
<root>...</root>
```

which, when opened in IE9, neatly displays the transformed xml contained above in the root element.

**Question 1**
Is there a processing instruction or similar available to include the source xml into the xml to be opened, somewhat like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xslt" ?>
<... instruction to include source file data.xml>
```

**Question 2**
The file opened has extension xml. Is there a way to change file contents so it is valid html, allowing the file to be saved with extension html, so that when opened, the default browser will be selected (simply changing extension to html obviously does not have the desired effect so some structural change is necessary) ?

**Question 3**
My goal is to query a db to get the data to be parsed by the xslt code. What is the best way to do this (no problem if this includes javascript)?

**Question 4**
Standard db utilities may export query results in attribute-centered fashion (column names and values being represented as attribute names and values). This may involve pre-parsing the xml from db in order to convert it to parent-child fashion (columns as children instead of attributes). What is the best way to do this pre-parsing (note: I already have the xslt for this; I wonder about the data flow and when/how to run two xslt's in sequence) and then apply test.xslt (preferably without saving intermediate xml result files on the server)?

**Question 5**
When I open above xml in IE9, this works fine as said. But opening it in Firefox errors (RTF issue, apparently I need to use Firefox's node-set function but I still have to discover which namespace that has), and Opera/Chrome/Safari do not show any content. What exactly are the prerequisites for the various browsers where can I find more information on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1** If you start by serving an html file which then accesses the xml and xslt via javascript it naturally has access to both the input and the output of the xslt. If you are serving the xml and initiating the transformation using xml-stylesheet pi, then perhaps the best thing to do (depending on what you want to do) is to stuff the original source into the output, then javascript in the generated page can access it if needed, eg

```
 <xsl:template matcj="whatever">
    <html>
      <head>
        <script id="source" type="x-xml-spurce">
           <xsl:copy-of select="/"/>
         </script>
      .... whatever you were going to do
```

then if you need to access the source in response to a user action on the page, a script can retrieve the script with id source and do whatever is needed. (If there is a possibility of the the source including the string  you have to code it a bit more defensively).

**Q2** If you want to use the xml-stylesheet API then you have to serve it as xml. However you can instead just serve html and then access the xml and xslt from within a script in the html page using the browsers javascip xslt api. as noted above that is more flexible than the xml-stylesheet mechanism.

**Q3** pass

**Q4** If you are accessing the xslt from javascript then it is easy to chain the output of one to the input of another without writing back to the server as you just have access to the result as a DOM node (or string, depending)

Answer (score 1):

Answer to question 5: Firefox/Mozilla, Opera, Safari, Chrome all support the [EXSLT node-set extension function](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) in the namespace `http://exslt.org/common`, for IE and MSXML you can use script (imported) inside the XSLT stylesheet to allow it to support that namespace too, see http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.de/2007/05/exslt-node-set-function.html. That way inside the main stylesheet where you need to use the `node-set` function you don't need to write different code to cater for the different namespaces.

Comment: I actually tried all that already - without effect so I wondered whether different browsers would need different setup - deducing from your answer that is not the case (except for node-set function) so probably I am erroring in code. I will double-check that!

Comment: Indeed - I made a mistake in coding. It opens correctly now in all browsers except Chrome. This solves question 5; now for the rest of them :-)